# Two new conjectures related to Lemoine's and Goldbach's

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures, goldbachs-conjecture

Lemoine's conjecture can be written:

$2n + 1 = p + 2q$ always has a solution in primes $p$ and $q$ (not necessarily distinct) for $n > 2$.

It appears that the following very similar conjectures (also applying to the relations between an odd number, a prime and a semi-prime)  can also be verified for values of o greater than 2 millions.

1. $O = 2n + 1 = p - 2q$ always has a solution in distinct odd primes $p$ and $q$ for $O \geq 5$
2. $O = 2n + 1 = 2q - p$ always has a solution in $p$ and $q$ with $q < p$, $p$ being an odd prime and $q$ being 1 or an odd prime and $O \geq 1$

The second can also be written as:

For every odd positive integer $O$ there exists two distinct odd primes (from primes and 1) $p_0$ and $p_1$ such that $p_1$ is the average of $O$ and $p_0$.

which makes it very similar to one of the possible formulations of Goldbach's seen in [Is every composite number the average of two primes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183652/is-every-composite-number-the-average-of-two-primes)

Has anybody seen these two conjectures anywhere before?

Comment: I like your spacing. Your use of $O$ and $o$, not so much,